# Creating an efficient file-based index that can be incrementally updated

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, indexing, persistence

As a research project I'm currently writing a **document-oriented database** from scratch in Python. Like MongoDB, the database supports the creation of indexes on arbitrary document keys. These indexes are currently implemented using two simple dictionaries: The first contains as key the (possibly hashed) value of the indexed field and as value the **store keys** of all documents associated with that field value, which allows the DB to locate the document on disk. The second dictionary contains the inverse of that, i.e. as a key the **store key** of a given document and as value the (hashed) value of the indexed field (which makes removing document from the index more efficient). An example:

```
doc1 = {'foo' : 'bar'} # store-key : doc1
doc2 = {'foo' : 'baz'} # store-key : doc2
doc3 = {'foo' : 'bar'} # store-key : doc3
```

For the `foo` field, the index dictionaries for these documents would look like this:

```
foo_index = {'bar' : ['doc1','doc3'],'baz' : ['doc2']}
foo_reverse_index = {'doc1' : ['bar'],'doc2' : ['baz'], 'doc3' : ['bar']}
```

(please not that the reverse index also consists of lists of values [and not single values] to accommodate indexing of list fields, in which case each element of the list field would be contained in the index separately)

During normal operation, the index resides in memory and is updated in real time after each insert/update/delete operation. To persist it, it gets serialized (e.g. as JSON object) and stored to disk, which works reasonably well for index sizes up to a few 100k entries. However, as the database size grows the index loading times at program startup become problematic, and committing changes in *realtime* to disk becomes nearly impossible since writing of the index incurs a large overhead.

Hence I'm looking for an implementation of a persistent index which allows for efficient **incremental** updates, or, expressed differently, does not require rewriting the whole index when persisting it to disk. What would be a suitable strategy for approaching this problem? I thought about using a linked-list to implement an addressable storage space to which objects could be written but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is limited to the update of the index for persistence; the extra time at program startup is not a major one and can not really be avoided.

One approach is to use a preallocation of disk space for the index (possibly for other collections too). In the preallocation, you define an empirical size associated with each entry of the index as well as the total size of the index on the disk. For example 1024 bytes for each entry of the index and a total of 1000 entries.
The strategy allows for direct access to each entry of the index on disk. You just have to store the position on the disk along with the index in memory. Any time you update an entry of the index in memory, you point directly to its exact location on the disk and rewrite only a single entry.

If it happens that the first index file is full, just create a second file; always preallocate the space for your file on disk (1024*1000 bytes). You should also preallocate the space for your other data, and choose to use multiple fixed-size files instead of a single large file

If it happens that some entries of the index require more than 1024 bytes, simply create an extra index file for larger entries; for example 2048 bytes per entry and a total of 100 entries.
The most important is to used fixed size index entries for direct access.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this definitely points in the right direction and is in my line of thinking about his problem. Currently I'm reading through the SQLite source code to see how they solve this problem. Do you know any more specific resources about this topic?

Comment: I do not know any specific resource about the topic. If you know any database provider that release the internal documentation, I think it is the point to start with. And if the answer is good enough, do not forget to accept it.